# Access VBA Recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset, continuous-forms

I have an access database that contains a table with employee information. My issue is that I want to loop through another table in order to determine if a specific characteristic is true or false first, then display all the records that are true in a continous form. It still populates all the records not just the ones that are true. Please see code below.

```
Private Sub RunQuery_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dba As Database
Dim tbl As Recordset
Dim Code As String
Dim status As String

Set dba = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeName,SSN,Location,SystemAssignedPersonID FROM dbo_tbl_Random "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE MenuUsed = 'Random' ORDER BY Location,EmployeeName"
Set tbl = dba.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
With tbl
  .MoveFirst
  If tbl.EOF Then
    MsgBox "There are no employees on Random at this time.", , "Oops! Try Again"
  Else
    Do Until tbl.EOF
      status = getEmpStatusID(tbl!SystemAssignedPersonID)
      If status = "A" Then
        Set Me.Recordset = tbl
        .MoveNext
      Else
        .MoveNext
      End If
    Loop
  End If
End With
Set tbl = Nothing
Set dba = Nothing
End Sub
```

The getEmpStatusID is a seperate function that is not giving me trouble. It looks up the Employee ID to get the information and returns it fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this need to be done as a loop? Why not use no recordsets and just do this all through SQL?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Brad I am not as familiar with complicated SQL statements wirtten into VB. If you could provide some guidance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It will be much simpler than manipulating recordsets. What does `getEmpStatusID` do?

Comment: getEmpStatusID takes the SystemAssignedPersonID, which is a unique number assigned to each employee (no duplicates) and looks into another table to find the employee statusm hence to 'A' for Active and 'T' for Termed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're most of the way there already. Depending on what `getEmpStatusID` does you can do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeName,SSN,Location,T.SystemAssignedPersonID 
FROM dbo_tbl_Random R
Inner JOin Table_Where_Status_Is_Found as T 
    on T.SystemAssignedPersonID = R.SystemAssignedPersonID
WHERE MenuUsed = 'Random' and T.SystemAssignedPersonID = 'A'
ORDER BY Location,EmployeeName
```

Use that as the rowsource for your form and don't use VBA. Your form will not be updatable because you used `distinct`, though. Is that necessary?

Comment: It is not necessary. Thanks so much!

Comment: I updated the query. you can join those two tables together on your common column. if there are no duplicates of SystemAssignedPersonID in your other table that is called your `Primary Key` (`PK`). If the data in column `SystemAssignedPersonID` of `dbo_tbl_Random` are constrained to only be values from your `SystemAssignedPersonID` column of your first table then this column is called a `Foreign Key`.

Comment: You can make this happen in the query designer but putting those two tables in then clicking on your PK in your first table then dragging and dropping to the FK in the other table. this will create the join for you.

Comment: it's not pulling any records at all now. I think I may be trying to make this more complicated than it should be.

Comment: The tables are in two different databases if that helps?

Comment: Are the tables set up as linked tables so they are both accessible from one data file? If no records are showing up then try without any filters (i.e. no `Where` clause)

Comment: I've got it!! Thank you for all your guidance!